# Not able to clone vsts repo in my local jenkins via alternate git credential

Tags: macos, jenkins, azure-devops

Not able to clone vsts repo in my local jenkins via alternate git credential, my jenkins is on MACOS. The solution below is not working for me, please assist.

Build hangs at
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://yyyy.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Subway%20Digital%20DevOps/_git/zzzz

> git init /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Test_Digital_Devops_repo # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from https://yyyy.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/zzzz/_git/zzzz
>   git --version # timeout=10
>   using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Standalone123n
>   git fetch --tags --progress https://yyyy.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/zzzz/_git/zzzz +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Comment: Can you clone your vsts git repo successful now?

Answer (score 1):

The URL for VSTS git repo should be:

```
https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_git/repo
```

To provider **alternate credential** during git clone, you should use the URL as:

```
https://SeconaryUsername:SeconaryPassword@account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_git/repo
```

So when you execute `git clone https://SeconaryUsername:SeconaryPassword@account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/project/_git/repo`, it can clone the VSTS git repo successful.

**BTW:** you can also provider personal access token (**PAT**) for authentication. The URL format shoule be:

```
https://Personal%20Access%20Token:PAT@account.visualstudio.com/project/_git/repo
```